# strip_tags - Strip <a> tags from a <img>

Tags: php, strip-tags

Is it possible to us strip_tags to remove  tags that are linking on an image?

For instance I want

```
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
```

to be

```
<img src="" />
```

I need to keep the image and remove all a tags that are around them. Besides using [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) I was hoping there was an easier way to do this

Comment: Yes, use regular `DOM`... It will be blindingly fast if you're used to simpleHTMLDom.

Comment: I found this thread which I believe should handle your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684395/strip-outer-element-ie-remove-parent-with-php-parser

Comment: Won't `strip_tags($str, '<img>')` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it using strip_tags. You can use a regular expression instead:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<a[^>]+\>(<img[^>]+\>)<\/a>/i", '$1', $text);
```

This way is faster and much easier than Simple HTML Dom

Comment: The problem is that this will replace texts such as `<atag href=""><img ></atag>` and `<a href="">words<img ></a>` incorrectly.

Comment: @Anonymous yup, you are right. But otherwise regex becomes huge. And such situations as you commented are rare. But anyway, yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do it:

```
$string = '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>';
$string = preg_replace('/(<a(?: [^>]+| |)>)(?:[^<]+|)<img(?: [^>]+| |)>(?:[^<]+|)(<\/a>)/','$1$2',$string);
```

This should replace anything within a link if there is an `<img>` tag within it from within a link declaration as long as there are no other tags in between the link.

If you want to only replace the `<img>` tag portion under the same circumstances, you can use:

```
$string = '<a href=""><img src="" /></a>';
$string = preg_replace('/(<a(?: [^>]+| |)>)([^<]+|)<img(?: [^>]+| |)>([^<]+|)(<\/a>)/','$1$2$3$4',$string);
```